# Sql Select not existing record?

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle, oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am trying to modify following 3 queries into one query with Final output.

The First Query Returns List of ids and Places

```
Select id,place from Global where status='Y';
```

**Query example Output:-**

1)123,Delhi

2)345,Jammu

3)456,Haryana

Then I want to send this output to

**Licence, and DrvingLicence** tables to filter ,if the id presents in either of this tables exclude the id from final output.

**licenceId=id and drivingLicenceNo=id**

```
Select licenceId from Licence table where state='MO' and licenceid=:id
Select drivingLicenceNo from DrvingLicence table where DOB='12/12/1978' and drivingLicenceNo=:id
```

**Place** is only present in **"Global"** table which should be present in Final output.

**Final Output:**

1)123,Delhi

Assuming id=345 present in Licence table and id=456 present in DrvingLicence table

Comment: Are you using MySQL or Oracle?

Comment: Some sample table data and the expected result would help - all as formatted text, not images. ([mcve].)

Answer (score 1):

Can you try this one ,it worked right for me. Final output is 123,Delhi

```
select * from global g
where not exists (select 1 from Licence l where l.licenceId=g.id and l.state='MO')
and not exists (select 1 from DrvingLicence dl where dl.drivingLicenceNo=g.id and dob=to_date('12121978','ddmmyyyy'))
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
select 
    id,
    place 
from Global g
where status='Y'
and NOT EXISTS (
    select
        licenceId
    from Licence l
    on g.id = l.licenceId
)
OR NOT EXISTS (
    select
        drivingLicenceNo
    from DrvingLicence dl
    on g.id = dl.drivingLicenceNo
);
```

Comment: Does this return unique records?how it will behave if the record present in two tables?

Comment: @NightHawk you should try to run it.

Comment: Sorry getting syntax error You have an error in your SQL syntax; it seems the error is around: 'on g.id = l.licenceId ) OR NOT EXISTS ( select drivingLicenceNo ' at line 12

Comment: its due "on".But query still returns records which are present in other tables.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe use some JOINS

```
Select g.id,g.place 
  from Global g 
      INNER JOIN Licence li ON g.id != li.id 
      INNER JOIN DrvingLicence dl ON g.id != dl.id 
 WHERE g.status='Y' 
   AND li.state='MO' 
   AND dl.DOB='12/12/1978';
```

Comment: Hi there! Welcome to SO. Next time try to format your answer (this time I did it for you, just check the Edit page and take a look). You just need to add a blank line before your code (form whatever text) and either four spaces or a tab before every line of code. Hope you enjoy SO.

Comment: sorry this is still giving a record which is in Licence table.

Comment: Maybe use the other answer but instead of the OR put an AND, and instead of the ON in the subquerys use WHERE

Answer (score 0):

Try this one instead!

```
SELECT * FROM GLOBAL g
WHERE g.id NOT IN (Select licenceId from Licence table where state='MO',Select drivingLicenceNo from DrvingLicence table where DOB='12/12/1978')
```

Hope it works..